# Compare python xml item output to list

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml.etree

I am farely new at python. I am currently working on a little project and I have a XML document in this structure.

```
<commands>
 <level1 name="sh">show></level1>
  <level2 name="ip">ip</level2>
   <level3 name="int">interface</level3>
    <level4 name="br">show ip interface brief</level4>
 <level1 name="int>interface</level1>
</commands>
```

What I need to do is to extract the attribute values from all elements and compare them to a list.

```
for in i tree.iter():
 attrib = i.items()
 x = ['name', 'sh']
 if attrib.index(0) in x
   print "BLa"
```

My problem is that I get a error that says "ValueError: 0 is not in list". I have tried much different things to see if it acts like a list but it doesn't. Strangely enough when I print 'attrib' I see a list.

Directly from doc 2.7.3(My version) of xml.etree.ElemenTree.items() - "items()
    Returns the element attributes as a sequence of (name, value) pairs. The attributes are returned in an arbitrary order.

Please help me and please ask for any other information.

Edit: To clarify I want to match a list say x = ['sh',ip,'int','br'] to every element value until every list index is matched and you come to a final elementtext which says "show ip interface brief"

Comment: What is the code for extracting your xml data? <commands> should be a root node if there's nothing more in the file. I could not find out that items() is recursive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I see iter() is recursive:

```
dicts = []
for node in root.iter():
    if node.tag == 'level1':
        dicts.append({}) # create new dict for tag chain
    if dicts and 'name' in node.attrib.keys():
        dicts[-1][node.attrib['name']] = node.text.rstrip().split() # list of words
```

Output for dicts:

```
{'sh': ['show'], 'br': ['show', 'ip', 'interface', 'brief'], 'ip': ['ip'], 'int': ['interface']}
{'int': ['interface']}
```

Comment: You can call iter() in your recursive function if number of levels should not raise stack overflow error, i.e. < sys.getrecursionlimit().